# push footer to bottom of page unless there is content to push it down without fixed height

Tags: html, css

I AM LOOKING FOR EXAMPLES WITHOUT `position: absolute; bottom: 0` or `position: fixed`.

Below is an example of the layout I have.

I want to position the footer at the bottom of the page if there is not enough content to push it down so I am looking for a `min-height` that somehow pushes the footer to the bottom.

```css
.application-layout__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.button__left {
  float: left;
}

.button__right {
  float: right;
}

.application-layout__button-group {
  clear: both;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: #0065bd;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 42px;
}

.page-footer nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 21px 0;
}

.page-footer nav a {
  color: #fff;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="application-layout__container">
        <div class="application-layout__header">
          <h1>
        Application
      </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="application-layout__body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input">Input</label>
              <input id="input" type="text" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="application-layout__button-group">
          <div class="button__left">
            <button type="button">
              Back
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button__right">
            <button type="button">
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      <nav>
        <a href="one">one</a>
        <a href="two">two</a>
        <a href="three">three</a>
        <a href="four">four</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you define height in px for footer?

Comment: trying to avoid defining fixed heights if possible

Comment: What's wrong with `position`

Comment: Considering your requirements, I think you must add some JS to your page.

Comment: I think you can do it with something like `min-height: calc(100vh - 395px);` for `application-layout__container`.  but I would like to avoid the specific `395px`

Answer (score -2):

I don't see what the problem with using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` is.

```css
.application-layout__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.button__left {
  float: left;
}

.button__right {
  float: right;
}

.application-layout__button-group {
  clear: both;
}

.page-footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
  background-color: #0065bd;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 42px;
}

.page-footer nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 21px 0;
}

.page-footer nav a {
  color: #fff;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="application-layout__container">
        <div class="application-layout__header">
          <h1>
        Application
      </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="application-layout__body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input">Input</label>
              <input id="input" type="text" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="application-layout__button-group">
          <div class="button__left">
            <button type="button">
              Back
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="button__right">
            <button type="button">
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      <nav>
        <a href="one">one</a>
        <a href="two">two</a>
        <a href="three">three</a>
        <a href="four">four</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because I want the content to be pushed down if there is more than a screen full of content

Comment: What do you mean by "pushed down," @dagda1?

Comment: I want it to behave normally if there is a lot of content above it

Comment: That would require a javascript conditional

Comment: How do you know?